# How to find out duplicate Elements in Xelement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to find out the duplicate Elements in XElement , and make a generic function to remove duplicates .Something like:

```
 public List<Xelement>RemoveDuplicatesFromXml(List<Xelement> xele)
{ // pass the Xelement List in the Argument and get the List back , after deleting the  duplicate entries.                                       
  return xele;
}
```

the xml is as follows:

```
<Execute ID="7300" Attrib1="xyz"    Attrib2="abc" Attrib3="mno" Attrib4="pqr" Attrib5="BCD" />
<Execute ID="7301" Attrib1="xyz"    Attrib2="abc" Attrib3="mno" Attrib4="pqr" Attrib5="BCD" />
<Execute ID="7302" Attrib1="xyz1"    Attrib2="abc" Attrib3="mno" Attrib4="pqr" Attrib5="BCD" />
```

I want get duplicates on every attribute excluding ID ,and then delete the one having lesser ID.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom `IEqualityComparer` for this task

```
class XComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public IList<string> _exceptions;
    public XComparer(params string[] exceptions)
    {
        _exceptions = new List<string>(exceptions);
    }

    public bool Equals(XElement a, XElement b)
    {
        var attA = a.Attributes().ToList();
        var attB = b.Attributes().ToList();

        var setA = AttributeNames(attA);
        var setB = AttributeNames(attB);

        if (!setA.SetEquals(setB))
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var e in setA)
        {
            var xa = attA.First(x => x.Name.LocalName == e);
            var xb = attB.First(x => x.Name.LocalName == e);

            if (xa.Value == null && xb.Value == null)
                continue;

            if (xa.Value == null || xb.Value == null)
                return false;

            if (!xa.Value.Equals(xb.Value))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private HashSet<string> AttributeNames(IList<XAttribute> e)
    {
        return new HashSet<string>(e.Select(x =>x.Name.LocalName).Except(_exceptions));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement e)
    {
        var h = 0;

        var atts = e.Attributes().ToList();
        var names = AttributeNames(atts);

        foreach (var a in names)
        {
            var xa = atts.First(x => x.Name.LocalName == a);

            if (xa.Value != null)
            {
                h = h ^ xa.Value.GetHashCode();
            }           
        }

        return h;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var comp = new XComparer("ID");
var distXEle = xele.Distinct(comp);
```

Please note that `IEqualityComparer` implementation in this answer only compare `LocalName` and doesn't take namespace into considerataion. If you have element with duplicate local name attribute, then this implementation will take the first one.

You can see the demo here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/w2DteS

---

### Edit

If you want to

> delete the one having lesser ID

It means you want the largest ID, then you can chain the `.Distinct` call with `.Select`.

```
var comp = new XComparer("ID");
var distXEle = xele
    .Distinct(comp)
    .Select(z => xele
        .Where(a => comp.Equals(z, a))
        .OrderByDescending(a => int.Parse(a.Attribute("ID").Value))
        .First()
    );
```

It will guarantee that you get the element with largest ID.

Comment: This solution will not guarantee that distinct elements have min `ID`. And I think checking `XAttribute.Value` for `null` is redundant.  `XAttribute.Value` cannot be `null`

Comment: @Fabio See edit. It seems that OP wants the *largest* ID instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq GroupBy

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
var groups = doc.Root
                .Elements()
                .GroupBy(element => new
                {
                    Attrib1 = element.Attribute("Attrib1").Value,
                    Attrib2 = element.Attribute("Attrib2").Value,
                    Attrib3 = element.Attribute("Attrib3").Value,
                    Attrib4 = element.Attribute("Attrib4").Value,
                    Attrib5 = element.Attribute("Attrib5").Value
                });

var duplicates = group1.SelectMany(group => 
{
    if(group.Count() == 1) // remove this if you want only duplicates
    {
        return group;
    }

    int minId = group.Min(element => int.Parse(element.Attribute("ID").Value));
    return group.Where(element => int.Parse(element.Attribute("ID").Value) > minId);
});
```

Solution above will remove elements with lesser `ID` which have duplicates by attributes.
If you want return only elements which have duplicates then remove `if` fork from last lambda